# How to receive strings with ncurses?

Tags: c++, string, ncurses

I'm trying to ask the user to enter a random word, but when I go to try to store it, the normal `cin` isn't working and just seems to be confusing ncurses. I've tried other functions like `wgetstr()` but it takes a char and not a string. I've been attempting multiple conversion functions like `c_str()` but nothing. Does anybody have any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getstr()` family of functions **do** return null-terminated strings, not just a single character. It's C library, there isn't any `std::string` type.

You must supply a suitable large buffer for the functions. It is more safe to use `getnstr` which limits the number of read characters.

```
char buffer[256];
int result = getnstr(buffer,sizeof(buffer)-1);//Make space for '\0'
assert(results!=-1);
buffer[sizeof(buffer)-1] = '\0'; // Force null-termination in the edge case.
size_t length = strlen(buffer);
```

I am not 100% sure whether the limit on `n` read characters includes the null byte, if it works as `strncpy`, it might not and in that case it's better to leave a space for it and add it explicitly.

Comment: That ("100% sure") would be answered if you read the [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getstr.3x.html#h2-PORTABILITY).

Comment: I did read [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getstr), which is apparently not complete.

Comment: I don't use that site (it's usually far out of date, poorly formatted, etc., as discussed [here](https://invisible-island.net/scripts/man2html.html)).  The up-to-date manual page does provide the suggested information.

Comment: I'm pretty new to C++ and I just recently learned about Ncurses. I'm confused as to what the buffer is for. Is the main goal just to "get rid of" the null byte. Also, what is the last line for?

Comment: @Barety The buffer will store the string read from the terminal, that is what you wanted , right? The last line will retrieve the length of the string inside the buffer if you need it. I added it just for reference. Or you can call `std::string(buffer)` to get C++ string version of it and work with that.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. But now that I know, why can't you just use `wgetstr()`. I know you mentioned that the `getstr()` group of functions returns null-terminated strings, but I'm still confused as to why go through all the trouble to get rid of the null byte? Sorry if there is something that I'm just not getting.

Comment: I am not getting rid of it, I am ensuring it is there.  The problem with `getstr` is that you have to provide a buffer for the function, okay you create `buffer[256]`, pass it to `getstr(buffer)`. What happens if user inputs a string of 257 chars? Well, `gestr` will happily write them to the buffer you pointed, expect it doesn't fit and no one will care, so you get buffer overflow bug. Those functions are dangerous unless you can ensure the user cannot input string longer than the buffer.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. Thank you so much.